# NuGet packages.config in VCS or not?

Tags: .net, version-control, nuget

Is is advisable to check in the NuGet `packages.config` to my VCS (e.g. Mercurial)? Or is it better to ignore the file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Definitely check this in.**

When someone else clones/forks/copies your repository from the the repo-source(aka Origin) they need to know which packages the solution requires.

This is the magic file that has those answers.

NOTE: having this file does not mean you have the *actual* nuget packages on the person's local computer. That's a different topic -> i personally always have *Nuget Package Restore* set to on, for every solution.